# In Ruby on Rails, should we use content_for?(:foobar)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is for Rails 3, almost always I think a `content_for?(:foo)` is followed by `content_for(:foo)`  (in haml):

```
%title= content_for?(:title_for_page) ? "#{content_for(:title_for_page)} - Our great website" : 'Our great website'
```

So instead of doing 2 lookups, isn't it better to just do 1 lookup and use longer code:

```
- title_for_page = content_for(:title_for_page)    # is "" when not previously set
%title= title_for_page.blank? ? 'Our great website' : "#{title_for_page} - Our great website"
```

?  But if `content_for?` is implemented as a hash, then maybe it is super quick anyway, comparable to the `blank?` anyways?

Comment: you've got a typo in the title, it should be content_for ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A one-liner to solve the problem:

```
- title_for_page = (c = content_for(:title_for_page)).blank? ? 'Our great website' : "#{c} - Our great website"
```

Comment: looks good except I am worried it also introduces a new local variable `c` that isn't so obvious (as opposed to `i` used for a loop which is very obvious use pattern)

Comment: i usually reserve this one-character variables to this kind of situation. I agree with you that you should be cautious when using locals but i think if you follow this rule-of-thumb you should be good to go :)

Comment: Why create a new local variable? my take: `= content_for?(:title_for_page) ? "#{yield(:title_for_page)} - Our great website" : "Our great website"`

Answer (score 2):

Only way to find out is to test :)

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > h = {:mike => "test"}
 => {:mike=>"test"} 

ruby-1.9.2-p136 :004 > Benchmark.ms do
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :005 >     h[:mike].present?
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :006?>   end
 => 0.029087066650390625 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :007 > Benchmark.ms do
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :008 >     h[:mike].blank?
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :009?>   end
 => 0.011205673217773438
```

I am using `present?`, [as per the source of `content_for?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for-3F)

Interesting that `blank?` is faster than `present?`, isn't it? Time to explore.

[Lets look at the source code for `present?`:](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F)

Woah, it turns out `present?` just calls `blank?` and negates it.